# About osx Extracting push notification package failed

Tags: safari

I use https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW22

createPushPackage.php

get pushpackage.zip
but always get an error message

[2016/11/16 11:35:04]{"logs":["Extracting push notification package failed"]}

What steps I made wrong?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to accomplish and what specific steps you took.  If you don't understand the purpose of one or more of the steps you are taking, you might find that asking about those specific steps will yield actionable answers.

Comment: i want safari get my pushPackage.zip but i create the zip and use php function echo file_get_contents($package_path); it's work but still get "logs":["Extracting push notification package failed" PS:Zip has been created.